# Travis build can't find generated include files

Tags: travis-ci

My project builds a program that generates header files used by my main executable. It generated the files successfully and I even checked the destination folder and it is there. However clang errors out cos it can't find the header file. The same build on appveyor builds just fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And which general rule am I not following?

Answer (score 0):

The files aren't being created with the appropriate access permissions for the owner (mainly read). Clang's default error message for this is it can't find the file when in truh it failed to open the file.